# unable to pass variables between jsp templates

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm unable to pass variables from a.jsp to b.jsp, following is what I tried and the output. Can someone please help? Thanks.

a.jsp

```
start including
<jsp:include page="b.jsp">
<jsp:param name="somevar" value="zzzz" />
</jsp:include>
 stop including
```

b.jsp

```
${somevar}
${param.somevar}
<%=request.getParameter("somevar")%>
```

output

```
start including


null
stop including
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>

    <jsp:include page="b.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="something" value="something" />
    </jsp:include>

    <h1>Bye World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In the b.jsp page use the following code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSP Param example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <c:out value="${param.something}" />
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The output must be

```
Hello world!
something 
Bye World
```

Try to avoid java code in JSP pages as it is not advisable. For more details, have a look at this answer [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/695657)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your param before include.

```
start including
<jsp:params>
    <jsp:param name="somevar" value="zzzz" />
</jsp:params>

<jsp:include page="b.jsp">
</jsp:include>
stop including
```

And can u try this in b.jsp:

```
<%=request.getParameter("somevar");%>
```

What is output?

Comment: I got a compile error " The jsp:param action must not be used outside the jsp:include, jsp:forward, or jsp:params elements" with that.